# I can't create multiple object of an entity at once

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm learning Symfony and I have a situation where I need, after a form, to create multiple object of an entity A.

All these objects are quite identical but just the value of one field change which is a relation OneToMany to an entity B. In the form this relation is selected with checkbox (that are EntityType related to B), and so I want to create one object A for each checked boxes.
My issue is that the First's form allows me to create only one object of First type at a time.
It is a project given by my teachers, and I mustn't create a ManyToMany relation.

Can somebody help me?

Here is the code in the Controller:

```
$A = new A();

$form = $this->createForm(AType::class, $A);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($A);
        $entityManager->flush();
}
```

And here is the code in the FormType:

```
$builder
        ->add('anotherField')
        ->add('idB', EntityType::class, [
                'label' => 'B',
                'class' => B::class,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true
        ])
;
```

Comment: `A` and `B` won't help us provide a realistic answer to your question (we can't tell if you made a typo error for example). I suggest you to edit your question, add bboth entities (id, relation is the minimum required), your controller as is, and your form builder as is.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, with one form submission you wish to save multiple entities to the database. I would clone all the form data into a new object, make changes and then persist all and flush like so:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

    $original = $form->getData();
    $copy = clone $original;

    // here you can make changes to your copy.  

    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entityManager->persist($original);
    $entityManager->persist($copy);
    $entityManager->flush();
}
```

Comment: I've thought about it but the issue is that Symfony already load data in an object ($A), and it returns me an error since it gets an array instead of a B object:
`Expected argument of type "App\Entity\B or null", "instance of Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection" given at property path "idB".`